# Django form gets image data but not text

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

I have Django form that displays information about the property and the idea of this form is to allow users to amend information about their properties. When displaying the form only image data is displayed, everything else is blank. From  `if request.user.landlord_profile.landlord_id == project.landlord_id:` is the code for the form.

views.py

```
def project_detail(request, pk):
    project = Properties.objects.get(pk=pk)
    applyButton = Property_Applications.objects.filter(listing=project)
    propertyReview = Property_Reviews.objects.filter(property=project)
    # getting the urls
    property_images = Property_Images.objects.filter(property=project)
    context = {
        'project': project,
        'propertyReview': propertyReview,
        'property_images' : property_images,
           }
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        if request.user.last_name == 'False': # allows to tenant to view ads and apply for them if they meet the requirements
            tenant_profile = Tenant_Profile.objects.get(tenant=request.user.tenant_profile.tenant_id)
            if request.method == "POST":
                applyButton = Property_Applications(
                    user=request.user,
                    listing=project,)
                applyButton.save()
            context['applyButton'] = applyButton
            context['tenant_profile']= tenant_profile
        if request.user.landlord_profile.landlord_id == project.landlord_id: # if the landlord owns this ad, this let's him edit the ad
            change_listing_form = ManageListingForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=project)
            if request.method == 'POST':
                if change_listing_form.is_valid():
                    change_listing_form.landlord = request.user.landlord_profile
                    change_listing_form.save()
                    messages.success(request, f'Your account has been updated!')
                else:
                    change_listing_form = ManageListingForm()
            context['change_listing_form'] = change_listing_form
    return render(request, 'project_detail.html', context)
```

forms.py - ManageListingForm

```
class ManageListingForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Properties
        fields = ['description','rentPrice','tenantSalary','referenceRequired','image']
```

project_detail.html - this is what displays the form

```
{% elif request.user.landlord_profile.landlord_id == project.landlord_id%}
                        <p></p>
                        <div style="text-align: center">
                            <button class="open-button" onclick="openForm()">Manage your Spot</button>
                        </div>
                                <div class="form-popup" id="myForm">
                                  <form class="form-container text-dark" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">

                                      <label for="Viewing Date " class="text-white">Enter a time that suits you to host a viewing with {{ portal.tenant }}</label>
                                        <fieldset class="form-group col-md-12 bg-white border border-dark" style="margin: auto;padding: 10px">
                                            {% csrf_token %}
                                            {{change_listing_form | crispy}}
                                            <div class="text-center">
                                                <button type="submit" class="btn bg-dark text-white">Update your listing</button>
                                            </div>
                                        </fieldset>
                                      <p></p>
                                    <button type="button" class="btn cancel" onclick="closeForm()">Close</button>
                                  </form>
                                <!-- Manage Listing function if the user is the owner-->
                                </div>
                    {% endif %}
```

Image of the the form only display image data
[image: rm]

Answer (score 0):

```
test install !!(pillow for images )

pip install pillow 


default = just to look images at save it or another problem !
upload_to = destination file to load your images  

in Model.py
image = models.ImageField(upload_to='put Your folder her ', default='default.png',)
```

Comment: You might want to add more text explaining your answer

Comment: Please explain your answer.